# Use a button as a static label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a button as a label (and not a label) for visual purposes. In other words, I want a button that is unclickable and doesn't change pointer when moused over.

How does one do this in bootstrap? I have tried to use a button and then disabling it, but that changes the style of the button which I don't want. Example: 
[Bootply](http://bootply.com/XGGpN08BMq)

Is this the right approach?

Something else that crossed my mind is that there might be a way to use a label but style it as a button. Is this the right way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be a `<button>` and not a `<label>` (or `<div>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `disabled`

```
<button disabled class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Get Started</button>
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/sjINsL4PhB): style not changed when button is disabled

You can do this with css, Add this css if you don't want disabled button faded:

```
.btn.disabled, .btn[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .btn{
opacity:1 !important;
}
```

[Updated DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/vjGO6M41gp)

Comment: The style changes. The color is a bit faded and not as bright blue as normal. See: http://www.bootply.com/XGGpN08BMq

Comment: Ohhh so that style you was talking about. Disable button by default having those styles

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a bit unclear. I'll add the bootply example to the question.